# Spark aggregation - nested groups

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, aggregation-framework

Need help on nested grouping. Very new to spark and scala. Appreciate you expert advise.

I'm Working on a transformation for a mongo collection using spark. I'm working with IntelliJ-Idea. Here are the collection details:

```
{
_id:
customer:
product:
location:
date:
transType:
}
```

Use case: For each 'product' and for each location who are the customers with transaction type 'ordered'.

//output something like this

```
        {
        Product: ABCD
          location: North america
            customer: Cust 1, type: ordered
              total: 200
       }
       {
        Product: EFGH
          location: North america
            customer: Cust 2, type: Ordered
               total: 300
}
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("PVL").setMaster("local").
      set("spark.mongodb.input.uri","mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/product.transactionEvent").
      set("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/product.transctionResult")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val rdd = sc.loadFromMongoDB()
val aggRdd = rdd.withPipeline(Seq(
      Document.parse("{$match: {transType: 'ordered'}}"),
      Document.parse("""{ $group: {_id: {prodId: "$prodId", customer: "$customer", location: "$location", Transtype: "$Transtype"}, total: {$sum:1}}}"""),
      Document.parse("""{$group: {_Id: {prodId: "$_id.prodId"}, details: {$addToSet: {customer: "$_id.customer", location: "$_id.location", transType: "$_id.transType", total: "$total"}}}}""")))
```

But this is not working for some reason. Error is:

> 'unknown group operator 'prodId'' on server

First off, is it possible to do this kind of nesting in spark? If yes, what am 'I doing wrong?
Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: The error message is stating that your group field `prodId` doesn't exist in your `transactionEvent` collection. I would suggest to learn about [MongoDB Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/). Test your aggregation via [mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/) first to make sure it works.

Comment: Thanks Wan. I **do have** a field named prodId. I just did not list it here in the question but I do have it in the collection. I tested it in mongo shell as well and it is throwing the same error. I think this has something to do with my $group nesting.

Comment: You should update your question with the correct document example and also the aggregation example you test on the mongo shell. Otherwise it would be hard for people to help you without the proper context.

Comment: I think I know what the issue is. In one of the `$group` statements, I have the `_id` capitalized (like `_Id`). Once i removed that it worked fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what the issue is. In one of the $group statements, I have the _id capitalized (like _Id). Once I removed that it worked fine.

So in short: Errors like `unknown group operator` or `<field> should be inside the object` means, the code is not able to recognize the group operator/field. the reasons could be:

1. The primary field in the group _id could be capitalized
2. missing commas
3. No group operator declared for a group field
4. etc..

So please check your code for these errors.

Thanks